# NestedScrollView inside BottomSheet

Tags: android, bottom-sheet, android-nestedscrollview

I have a NestedScrollView inside a BottomSheet.
The problem is **just sometimes** NestedScrollView doesn't work and dragging on it detaches BottomSheet and starts dragging it.
Is there a bug in NesterScrollView?

Comment: I guess when there is no need of scrolling then it doesn't scroll.. What OS is it not working on?

Comment: sometimes there is need for scroll and content are under cover. Android 8 & 8.1

Comment: Have you tried this: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41263309/9763253)

Comment: @Ümañgßürmån Yes, as I said, I am currently using NestedScrollView

Comment: Show xml file..